# Best way to check if any value exists on ArrayList

Tags: c#, .net

I have `ArrayList`.
I want to check if any value exits in t his `ArrayList`.
I would like to use Any method (from `System.Linq` namespace), but I can use it only on `Array`, not `ArrayList`.

Is there any efficient way to check this?

Comment: Why do you still use an `ArrayList` instead of a generic `List<T>`?

Comment: Because it's old code and ArrayList were used.

Comment: @ogrod87 Then fix it, rather than leaving it broken.

Comment: If i could, then I will fix it :) it's not my code, so I can change this objects....

Answer (score 8):

Well, you could check the `.Count > 0`. But a better option would be *stop using `ArrayList`*. Since you know about `Any()` and `System.Linq`, I assume you're not using .NET 1.1; so use `List<T>` for some `T`, and all your problems will be solved. This has full LINQ-to-Objects usage, and is just a much better idea.

```
List<int> myInts = ...
bool anyAtAll = myInts.Any();
bool anyEvens = myInts.Any(x => (x % 2) == 0);
// etc
```

Answer (score 1):

use the link `.Cast` method to cast your array list to a generic type

```
ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();

bool hasItem = ar.Cast<int>().Any( i => i == 1);
```

Comment: @MarcGravell: You could construe the Contains() to meet the definition of Any I would think: "Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition." If it is contained, it satisfies the condition. Even if Contains() doesn't provide for an expression.

Comment: @OA0D show me how to use `Contains` to test "is there a person in the list whose name begins with `A`", then; I'll start: `bool b = list.Any(p => p.Name.StartsWith("A"));` - your turn...

Comment: @MarcGravell at any rate, I've fixed it.

Comment: @MarcGravell: You can't in that case, but in the OP's case Contains and Any could mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could always use the ArrayList.Count which will give you the number of object in your array. If its equal to 0 their nothing in it.

Comment: `ArrayList` has `Count`, not `Count()`; `Enumerable` has `Count`, but only for `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: But Count() give me all elemenets. I want to check only if one or more elements exists

Comment: Yeah well count give you the number of element inside that array so you can compare. Example If(ArrayList.Count > 0) then there is something in the array. If not well there nothing in it

Comment: But I'm thinking about efficient. There is big difference between Count and Any. Any is quicker.